# Including raphael js lib into android phonegap application

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, raphael

I'm trying to run some performance tests with phonegap and raphael js on android, but when i try to run the application logcat gives me the folowing error:

03-20 19:52:15.095: D/CordovaLog(4208): Uncaught ReferenceError: Raphael is not defined
03-20 19:52:15.095: E/Web Console(4208): Uncaught ReferenceError: Raphael is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/js/classes/bootstrapper.js:58

My index.html looks like this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information
    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
     KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />        
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova/cordova-android-2.5.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/raphael-min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery-min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">

                <p class="event listening"><a style="" href="informacoes.html">Ir para a p&aacute;gina de informa&ccedil;&otilde;es</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>     
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/classes/bootstrapper.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">

            app.testPeformance();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

bootstrapper.js

```
var app = {

        testPeformance : function () 

        {

            // Creates canvas 320 × 200 at 10, 50
            var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 320, 320);

            for (var i = 0; i < 500 ; i++ )
            {
                x = Math.floor( ( Math.random() *320) +1);
                y = Math.floor( ( Math.random() *320) +1);

                // Creates circle at x = 50, y = 40, with radius 10
                var circle = paper.circle(x, y, 30);
                // Sets the fill attribute of the circle to red (#f00)
                circle.attr("fill", "#f00");

                // Sets the stroke attribute of the circle to white
                circle.attr("stroke", "#fff");

            }

        }

}
```

It works perfectly on IOS simulator.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the web container (webkit) that android uses for phonegap applications does not support SVG graphics yet ( android 2.2 ).

:(